# Pythonic way to store and compare csv or xlsx attendance data

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

**Background**

I have the following in a .xlsx file when I run a report at work.

A1 - First Name
B1 - Last Name
C1 - Date Attended

Each row contains the data for each person that attended one of our events. I am building a program in python that will take a master.xlsx file and compare it with another .xlsx and give me the following output.

1. A .txt file with anyone who hasn't attended an event in the past 2 weeks.
2. A .txt file with anyone who hasn't attended an event in the past 4 weeks.
3. A .txt file with anyone who hasn't attended an event in 4+ weeks.
4. A new master.xlsx file with First_Name, Last_Name, Last_Date_Attended

The second .xlsx report is run weekly but actually has a month's worth of attendance data in it. That means if Joe Blow attended 6 times in a month Joe Blow will return 6 rows in the .xlsx file, each with a unique date. So I am going to iterate over the data, compare the dates and only keep the most recent one.

**The Question**

I have actually already done the above and my first inclination was to turn it into a dictionary in a dictionary. Where the last name is the key with values of 'first', 'date', 'total attended'. Total attended is calculated as part of the for loop.

But a dictionary in a dictionary just doesn't feel pythonic. I feel like I'm hacking a way around a simpler solution. Especially, once I begin writing the output files. Accessing values of a dict in dict doesn't feel right.

Thoughts or suggestions on a better way?

Here's a sample of the code I wrote last night:

```
data = [This is the data from the .xlsx as a list of lists]
final_data = dict()
dict_errors = 0

for i in data:
    if i[1] in final_data:
        final_data[i[1]]['total'] = final_data[i[1]]['total'] + 1
        if final_data[i[1]]['date'] < i[2]:
            final_data[i[1]]['date'] = i[2]
        else:
            final_data[i[1]] = {
                'first': i[0],
                'date': i[2],
                'total': 1
                }
    else:
        dict_errors += 1
```

Comment: Pythonic code is overrated! If it isn't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: @Coldspeed I'd strongly recommend you learn to refactor

Comment: Improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: How do you store your date?

Comment: @Coldspeed I use datetime to parse the data into the correct format. I just didn't include that part of the code.